# Counting total number of element occurrences in different length vectors

Tags: python, numpy, pandas

I have 3 very long (100K+ elements) vectors of different products names. Each vector has different length. What I want to do is to count in how many vectors each product is. So something like this:

```
v1 = ['product1','product2','product3']
v2 = ['product3','product1','product5','product7','product10']
v3 = ['product1','product10']

'product1' 3
'product2' 1
'product3' 2
'product5' 1
'product7' 1
'product10' 2
```

Products might be in any order within vector and within vector each product appears only once.

I wanted to use pandas `DataFrame` here, but all columns must be this same length. Also simple summing based on rows will not work, because this same product might be on different row in each column.

Does anyone has any idea what will be the best way to do this? I know that I can do simple bruteforce loop but I don't want to if I can use something from numpy or pandas.

Comment: If there are no duplicates in a certain vector `pd.value_counts(v1 + v2 + v3)` should do it.

Comment: @ayhan You are right, it's also working. Thank you!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [`Counter`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) and [`chain`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain) to do this in a few lines:

```
from collections import Counter
from itertools import chain

v1 = ['product1','product2','product3']
v2 = ['product3','product1','product5','product7','product10']
v3 = ['product1','product10']

c = Counter(chain(v1, v2, v3))
# more space-efficient than Counter(v1 + v2 + v3)
# Counter({'product1': 3, 'product10': 2, 'product3': 2, 'product7': 1, 'product5': 1, 'product2': 1})

c['product10']
# 2
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use Python build-in function `count`

```
(v1+v2+v3).count('product1')
Out[4]: 3
```

If you want to build a `dict`:

```
v=v1+v2+v3
dict((x,v.count(x)) for x in v)
Out[17]: 
{'product1': 3,
 'product10': 2,
 'product2': 1,
 'product3': 2,
 'product5': 1,
 'product7': 1}
```

Just for curiosity, I generated 5000 samples with product id from 0 to 100. An split them into 3 pieces.

```
import numpy as np
v = ['product' + str(x) for x in np.random.randint(0, 100, 5000)]
v1 = v[0:100]
v2 = v[100:4000]
v3 = v[4000:]
```

Then it just run a `%timeit` in IPython, using `collections.Counter`:

```
%timeit from collections import Counter
from itertools import chain
c = Counter(chain(v1, v2, v3))
c['product10']

The slowest run took 5.87 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an intermediate result is being cached 
1000000 loops, best of 3: 875 ns per loop
Out[30]: 47
```

using build-in `count`:

```
%timeit (v1+v2+v3).count('product10')
10000 loops, best of 3: 58.1 µs per loop
Out[31]: 47
```